# Unable to see string in rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on `c# winforms`. I have a `rich textbox` in my `main form`. Now I am using a class `HandleClient` in which I am using a thread in which I am calling a function. In that function, I have made a new object of my main form. My code is below

**Flow**

First of all, I am passing a port number via user and on button click, I am going to listen to it. For that, I have a class named `Server`

**Main Form**

```
port = Convert.ToInt32(tbPort.Text);
Server server = new Server(port);
if (btnListen.Text == "Listen")
{
     btnListen.Text = "Close";
     server.start();
}
```

The above object is created and the start method is called

**Server Class**

```
public Server(int port)
{
   this.port = port;
}

 public void start()
 {
        listner = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        listner.Start();
        listnerthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listner));
        listnerthread.Start();
 }

public void Listner()
{
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                TcpClient C = listner.AcceptTcpClient();
                HandleClient client = new HandleClient();
                client.startClient(C);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in listner");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

The above method is listening to the port. Also, my handle client function is also called. In which I am trying to display the incoming string to the rich text box

**Handle Client**

```
 // Buffer to store the response bytes.
byte[] data = new byte[9999];

Thread comThread;
public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
{
   this.clientsocket = inClientSocket;
   comThread = new Thread(doChat);
   comThread.Start();
}

private void doChat()
{
        MainForm form = new MainForm();

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                NetworkStream stream = clientsocket.GetStream();
                stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);                 

                responseData = BitConverter.ToString(data,0,bytes); 
                form.rtBRecievedData.Text = responseData;

                stream.Close();
                clientsocket.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                comThread.Abort();
            }
        }
}
```

The value of `responseData` is `01-01-01-01-00-01-00-19-F4-09-10-00-00-00-00-30-30-32-39-39-38-30-30-35-35-36-31-00-01-00-01-00-01-00-15-AA-10-00-00-00-00-30-30-32-39-39-38-30-30-35-35-36-31-12-00-12`

Now the main issue is that this string is not displaying on `rich text box`. I might be missing something that I am not able to understand.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you ever show the form?

Comment: @RonBeyer I am using the form to send a port number then receiving data which is on that port

Comment: Please check that "BitConverter.ToString(data,0,bytes)" is returning the string value. It can return a blank.

Comment: @Nurhan yes its returning a string

Comment: @Faisal When or where do you call the Show() method of the form?

Comment: @Nurhan I have updated my question you can see it. I answered your question

Comment: As I understood from your code, you try to reach the main form's textbox from the clients.cs but you are creating a new Main form which is another instance. You can not use that way.  (There are lots of chat program example you can use in the internet, I suggest you googgle them:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are attempting to display the information in a `TextBox` on a new instance of `MainForm` (upon which you have never called Show()) rather than your existing `MainForm`, in which the user has entered the port. To fix this, your `HandleClient` class needs a reference to the existing form.
Add fields to both your `Server` and `HandleClient` classes and adjust your constructors accordingly:

```
public Server(int port, Form mainForm)
{
    this.port = port;
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
}

public HandleClient (Form mainForm)
{
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
}
```

Now when creating the `Server`, you pass a reference to the current form with the`this` keyword and hence on to the `HandleClient`.

Finally you remove the line creating a new `MainForm` and use the field instead.

Comment: I have tried your way but it's giving me an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and `this.mainForm` is `null`

Comment: I have done the following `public MainForm mainForm { get; set; }` then `Server server = new Server(port, this.mainForm);` inside `server.cs` I have declared `public int port { get; set; }
        public MainForm mainForm { get; set; }` after that i have done `public Server(int port, MainForm mainForm)
        {
            this.port = port;
            this.mainForm = mainForm;

        }`

Comment: In my `server.cs` inside the listener, I have done the following `HandleClient client = new HandleClient(this.mainForm);`

Comment: Now in my `HandleClient.cs`, I have declared `public MainForm mainForm { get; set; }` and then `public HandleClient(MainForm mainForm)
        {
            this.mainForm = mainForm;
        }`

Comment: Finally, inside my `doChat()` method I have done `mainForm.rtBRecievedData.Text = responseData;` after this line I am getting exception

Comment: You should just have `Server server = new Server(port, this)` not `this.mainForm`. The form doesn't need a reference to itself.

Comment: Now I am getting exception `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rtBRecievedData' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`

Comment: You need to use Invoke in order to access the UI from a thread.  See Marc Gravell's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread/1803319)  Just use `RichTextBox.Invoke` for `Label.Invoke`

Comment: The given method in the link provided by your does works. But the resulting output is displaying in a rich text box while I am in debug mode. But when I tried to run it it's not displaying :(

Comment: Happy New Year. have a mega hangover and am only on my phone (not at my PC), so please treat this with caution. Are you sure that it is not working in run mode? Is it possible that the value is being set, but immediately overwritten with an empty string? Try testing for null/empty string before calling `Invoke`.

Comment: Happy New Year to you also :) 

All the things are working perfectly now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
form.rtBRecievedData.Text = responseData;
```

is within a loop.
But there is no Thread.Sleep() method.

form.rtBRecievedData.Text can be replace by empty string of responseData in the next round of execution of loop.

use the following code,

```
form.rtBRecievedData.Text += responseData;
```

resolve the issue.
And better to have sleep within the loop to give a delay in reading the port.

Comment: Did you change the = to += in form.rtBRecievedData.Text += responseData; ?

Comment: Is there any error, exceptions or just not showing the text? Please debug and check the value is assigned correctly.